# Prove that the set of all non-decreasing functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable.

Tags: real-analysis, number-theory

Please help me. How can I show that the set of non-decreasing function is uncountable. Stuck that this question!

Comment: if it was countable there would be a mapping from the set to $\mathbb{N}$. build a new function and prove it's not mapped by the mapping

Comment: Can you prove that the set of functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ is uncountable ? Then your answer should follow easily (think about differences)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are uncountably many infinite sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s. Indeed there are continuum many. For any such sequence $a_1,a_2,a_3, \dots$, we define a function $f$ from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$ as follows.

Let $f(1)=a_1+1$. For any $k\gt 1$, let $f(k)=f(k-1)+a_k$. This function is non-decreasing, and two different sequences $a_1,a_2,\dots$ and $b_1,b_2,\dots$ give rise to different functions.

We have described an injection from the set of sequences of $0$'s and $1$'s to the set of non-decreasing functions from $\mathbb{N}$ to $\mathbb{N}$. So the second set has cardinality greater than or equal to the cardinality of the first.